# Comparison of styleColorBar rows in Shiny's DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to do row comparison with styleColorBar.
In this sample, I want to compare Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width line by line.

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    iris2 <- iris[c(1:10),c(1,2)]
    
    observe({
      
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        dat <- datatable(iris2,
                         options = list(
                           paging = FALSE
                         )) %>%
          formatStyle('Sepal.Length',background = styleColorBar(iris2$Sepal.Length, '#66cdaa'),backgroundSize = '98% 88%',backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition = 'center') %>%
          formatStyle('Sepal.Width',background = styleColorBar(iris2$Sepal.Width, '#66cdaa'),backgroundSize = '98% 88%',backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition = 'center')
        return(dat)
      })
      
    })
    
  })
```

However, since styleColorBar is a comparison for each column, the maximum value and the minimum value are different on the left and right, and the bar length does not match

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    iris2 <- iris[c(1:10),c(1,2)]
    
    observe({
      
      max <- max(iris2[,1:2], na.rm = TRUE)
      max <- c(max,max)
      min <- min(iris2[,1:2], na.rm = TRUE)
      min <- c(min,min)
      iris2 <- rbind(iris2,max,min)
      
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        dat <- datatable(iris2,
                         options = list(
                           paging = FALSE
                         )) %>%
          formatStyle('Sepal.Length',background = styleColorBar(iris2$Sepal.Length, '#66cdaa'),backgroundSize = '98% 88%',backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition = 'center') %>%
          formatStyle('Sepal.Width',background = styleColorBar(iris2$Sepal.Width, '#66cdaa'),backgroundSize = '98% 88%',backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition = 'center')
        return(dat)
      })
      
    })
    
  })
```

So, I added the record of the maximum and minimum value of Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width to each column and made the bar length equal.
The left-right comparison in the bar went well, but not very cool.
Is there a way to hide the last two lines from the user?
Or can I justify the left and right bars without adding two lines?

Comment: Try something like: `dat <- datatable(iris2[1:10,]...` and see if that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
library(DT)

iris2 <- iris[1:10, c(1,2)]
datatable(iris2,
          options = list(
            paging = FALSE
          )) %>%
  formatStyle('Sepal.Length', 
              background = styleColorBar(c(iris2$Sepal.Length, iris2$Sepal.Width), '#66cdaa'), 
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%', 
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', 
              backgroundPosition = 'center') %>%
  formatStyle('Sepal.Width', 
              background = styleColorBar(c(iris2$Sepal.Length, iris2$Sepal.Width), '#66cdaa'), 
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%', 
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat', 
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```